# Как сменить динамически параметры свойств объекта ,установленных в Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript

Есть ли такая возможность?
Есть метод **Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()** .Он возвращает настройки свойства в виде объекта.
При попытке сменить их

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(user,'name').writable=true
```

результата нету.
Как поступить для смены настроек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {};
obj.newDataProperty = "abc";
var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, "newDataProperty");
descriptor.writable = false;
Object.defineProperty(obj, "newDataProperty", descriptor);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.